# Assistance with Progress Bar and backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am slowly getting my head around C# and I am having a play before I start my formal training in the new year. 
I have created a application that pulls data from a SQL database and displays in a dataGridView. This table can be very large in size and can take some time to load. I have changed the cursor for this time so the user can see something is happening. However I would like to add in a process bar. I have tired to follow a few tutorials with no luck. I have created the task in a method called doTask(). I have tried using Backgroundworker but for some reason my process bar never updates. Doesn't help that all the tutorials seem to just use a timer, rather then a real task.

From the videos I have seem when you call the RunWorkerAsync() which then in turn runs the method?

Any help would be great

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Internal use only. Do NOT sent installers or customers", "INTERNAL USE ONLY", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }

    private void getEventsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        // doTask();
    }

    public void doTask()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Events");
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);

        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"
        Select e.EventTime as 'Date/time', u.Username as 'User', e.CardNo as 'Token number', dev.PeripheralName as 'Where' , et.EventTypeDescription as 'Event', est.EventSubTypeDescription as 'Details'
        FROM Archive.dbo.Events e
        left join sdk.EventSubTypes est
        on e.EventSubType = est.EventSubTypeID
        join sdk.EventTypes et
        on e.EventType = et.EventTypeID
        join sdk.UsersEx as u
        on e.UserID = u.UserID
        join sdk.PeripheralNames as dev
        on e.Address = dev.SerialNumber
        order by EventTime asc
        ", cn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da.Fill(dt);
        archievegridview.DataSource = dt;
        label2.Text = archievegridview.Rows.Count.ToString();

        if (archievegridview.Rows.Count < 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Net2Archive data available", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

        cn.Close();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            doTask();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In what way would you like to display your progress? Could you know beforehand how many records you need to fetch? You could try measuring the progress using that

Comment: There could be any number of results in the table. The Query just views all the data in the tables I need

Comment: In your `doTask()` you have to add some `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress()`. That triggers a call to `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`. Now, as you have the code right now this is pretty pointless because there's no way of knowing when the process is going to end or when to update the loading bar. In this case I think the best way of handling this is having a gif image that you set to visible at the start of the task and set to invisible when the data is loaded. If this is Windows Forms you can keep the bw to do this or else the gif won't show any animations.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Are you sure you followed [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) step by step and read everything? Did you set `WorkerReportsProgress` correctly?

Comment: what happens when you debug this? and are you sure that your task doesnt complete quicker than you anticipate?Also, in terms of level of completeness, how are you measuring this?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am going to look into the further. I went with using a gif for the time being. Thank you everyone.